# CSS to select all li in ul

Tags: css, html-lists

I want to write a CSS selector that selects all li elements within a ul element in a document but I don't know how that would be done. Can you help?

Comment: Any `ul` element or just one particular such element? This goes down to just about the basics, and I suggest you peruse the many existing basic tutorials/guides out there which have the basics widely covered, as well as use search.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
ul > li {
  /* css styles go here */
}
```

or

```
ul li {
  /* css styles go here */
}
```

the first selects only direct children the second selects all `li` nested within an `ul`.

Comment: Probably, someone else with a duplicate answer.

Comment: +1 the first to answer. but the second part was enough according to OP

Comment: @Rab well, better than always doing only the minimum just for being first and trying to get upvotes, right?

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
ul li { /*css here */}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 ul li {
  /* your code here */
 }
```